# Query - Error assigning value to variable in VB

Tags: sql, vb6

I have the following code to query in VB6:

```
SQL = " if object_id('tempdb..#MovSeq','U') is not null drop table #MovSeq;" & _
    " declare @Data_Inicio datetime, @Data_Fim datetime; set dateformat dmy; set @Data_Inicio = DataInicio; set @Data_Fim = DataFinal; set @Data_Fim = DateAdd(day, +1, @Data_Fim); " & _
    " with Mov as ( SELECT EI.Cod_Empresa, EI.Cod_Estoque, EI.Cod_Produto, 'E' as Tipo_Mov, E.Dta_Entrada as Data_Mov, EI.id_Doc as NF, EI.Qtde, EI.V_Unitario, EI.V_Total " & _
      " from Entrada_Itens as EI inner join Entrada as E on EI.Cod_Empresa=E.Cod_Empresa and EI.id_Doc=E.id_Doc " & _
      " where E.Dta_Entrada >= @Data_Inicio and EI.Cod_Empresa='" & Sys.Empresa & "' and EI.Cod_Estoque='" & dcEstoque.BoundText & "' and EI.Cod_Produto='" & dtProdutos.BoundText & "' " & _
    " Union " & _
    " SELECT SI.Cod_Empresa, SI.Cod_Estoque, SI.Cod_Produto, 'S', S.Dta_Entrada , SI.id_Doc, -SI.Qtde, SI.V_Unitario, SI.V_Total " & _
      " from Saida_Itens as SI inner join Saida as S on SI.Cod_Empresa=S.Cod_Empresa and SI.id_Doc=S.id_Doc " & _
      " where S.Dta_Entrada >= @Data_Inicio and SI.Cod_Empresa='" & Sys.Empresa & "' and SI.Cod_Estoque='" & dcEstoque.BoundText & "' and SI.Cod_Produto='" & dtProdutos.BoundText & "' " & _
    " Union " & _
    " SELECT Cod_Empresa, Cod_Estoque, Cod_Produto, 'A', @Data_Inicio, null, null, null, null " & _
      " From Estoque " & _
      " where Cod_Empresa='" & Sys.Empresa & "' and Cod_Estoque='" & dcEstoque.BoundText & "' and Cod_Produto='" & dtProdutos.BoundText & "') " & _
    " SELECT *, Seq= row_number() over (partition by Cod_Empresa, Cod_Estoque, Cod_Produto order by Data_Mov desc, Tipo_Mov desc) into #MovSeq from Mov; " & _
    " create unique clustered index IndMovSeq on #MovSeq (Cod_Empresa, Cod_Estoque, Cod_Produto, Seq); " & _
    " SELECT M.Cod_Empresa, M.Cod_Estoque, M.Cod_Produto, P.Descricao," & _
          " Estoque= case when M.Seq=1 then E.Qtde_Estoque else (E.Qtde_Estoque - (SELECT sum(Mi.Qtde) from #MovSeq as Mi " & _
                                  " Where Mi.Cod_Empresa = M.Cod_Empresa And Mi.Cod_Estoque = M.Cod_Estoque And Mi.Cod_Produto = M.Cod_Produto and Mi.Seq < M.Seq)) end " & _
      " from #MovSeq as M inner join " & _
           " Estoque as E on M.Cod_Empresa=E.Cod_Empresa and M.Cod_Estoque=E.Cod_Estoque and M.Cod_Produto=E.Cod_Produto inner join " & _
           " Produtos as P on M.Cod_Empresa=P.Cod_Empresa and M.Cod_Estoque=P.Cod_Estoque and M.Cod_Produto=P.Cod_Produto " & _
      " where Data_Mov < @Data_Fim " & _
         " order by M.Cod_Empresa, M.Cod_Estoque, M.Cod_Produto, Seq desc; " & _
    " drop table #MovSeq;"
```

the error appears 'invalid columm name' when run showing DataInicio as a reason

I know the error is in the assignment of the variable. but how to solve.
Thanks for the help...

Comment: Are you fully escaping the values in the variables? debug.print the final sql and test in in SSMS. Consider making this an SP as all you are doing is supplying search arguments.

Comment: 'DataInicio' is a variable of the form in question. If you assign values ​​and run in SSMS works perfectly. How do I call a Stored Procedure within a form in VB6?

Answer (score 0):

Your type of code is very prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) attacks...

Are you escaping the variable values correctly? A simple quote (') in one of the variables can change the SQL string completely...

You should consider using parameters to pass values instead of building SQL commands using string concatenation.

Comment: the DataInicio variable is type date and is in the form.